# Método nextLine() no funciona correctamente en los ciclos (JAVA)

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Dime el numero");
        int x=leer.nextInt();
        String palabra;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
//cuando entra me ignora la el nextLine :c
            System.out.println("N "+(i+1)); 
            palabra=leer.nextLine();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Ey, que tal amigo!
En vez de nextLine() utiliza **next()**, tal vez te pueda solucionar ello.

!Espero te sirva, saludos!

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in); 
   System.out.println("Dime el numero"); 
   int x=leer.nextInt(); 
   String palabra; 
   for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {        
       System.out.println("N "+(i+1)); 
       palabra=leer.next(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es con `.nextInt()`. Cuando ingresas un número y presionas "Enter", `.nextInt()` consume solamente el número y no el final de la línea. El final de toda línea es "\n". Por lo tanto, cuando ejecutas `.nextLine()` consumes el "final de la línea".

Puedes resolver tu problema de las siguientes maneras:

- Agregar un `.nextLine()` extra, entre `.nextInt()` y `.nextLine()`.
  El `.nextLine()` extra consumirá el "final de la línea" siempre.

**Ejemplo de esto:**

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
String string1 = scanner.nextLine();
```

- Otra forma es utilizar `.nextLine()` en lugar de `.nextInt()`. para
  leer el número. Recuerda que `.nextLine()` consume siempre "el final
  de la línea". Dado que `.nextLine()` retorna un String, tienes que
  convertir ese String a Integer. Cómo?, usando
  `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

**Ejemplo de esto:**

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Si usas la segunda forma, puedes recibir una Exception del método `Integer.parseInt(...)` si el String que le pasas como argumento no puede ser convertido a Integer. Por ejemplo, si le pasas "HolaMundo" y tratas de convertir ese String a Integer, obviamente no se va a poder. Para manejar esas excepciones, deberás usar un bloque `try-catch`.

Espero haberte ayudado y esclarecido tu problema en detalle.
Saludos.